# How to fix BROADCAST_VARIABLE_NOT_LOADED when using a broadcasted spark variable in a udf?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Below is the code that produces the error. It tries to broadcast a dictionary to the cluster nodes in databricks.

```
erp_bu = src_config.select("erp_code", "bu").collect()
erp_bu_dic = {}
for row in erp_bu:
    if row['erp_code']:
        erp_bu_dic[row['erp_code']] = row['bu']
broadcast_erp_bu_dic = sc.broadcast(erp_bu_dic)
def lookup(x):
    return broadcast_erp_bu_dic.value[x]
u_lookup = udf(lookup)
j06 = j06.withColumn('business_unit', u_lookup("entity_source_id"))
display(j06)
```

The error I am getting is.

```
SparkException: com.databricks.spark.safespark.UDFException: 
INVALID_ARGUMENT: [BROADCAST_VARIABLE_NOT_LOADED] Broadcast variable `178` not loaded.
```

Comment: Maybe not the timeout but the size? How large is the dictionar you are trying to broadcast?